# How to use Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 2 on the same page

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-2, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a `Django` application which is written in `Bootstrap 4`. On one page I am using a control which is written in `Bootstrap 2`, So if I use `Bootstrap 2` on that page then controls works but other controls gets broke. If I use `Bootstrap 4` then other control works except for the one which is written in `Bootstrap 2` as `Bootstrap 4` is not backward compatible. Basically, I am trying to use [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) written in `bootstrap v2.3.2`. Is there any way to tackle this issue, any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might just as well use [zurb-foundation] framework for your control and Bootstrap 4 for the rest. It would be just as backwards and wrong as what you have now.

Comment: @WebDevBooster It is a pre written control in `Bootstrap 2`. It Won't be possible for me to rewrite it in `zurb-foundation`

Comment: And the fact that the question has only been viewed 14 times further underlines that most people didn't even bother to open the question when they looked at the title.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried [this](https://github.com/Nodws/bootstrap4-tagsinput) as suggested by [webdevbooster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8270343/webdevbooster) and it worked.